# calculatate experience from database data to current year month

Tags: php, mysql

Iam having database with columns year and month

```
       year  month   createdate
        1      2     2017-04-12 10:36:25
```

I want calculate experience from year month of created date to now(current year month)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html) function.

```
SELECT 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, created_date, now()) as year, 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, created_date, now()) - TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, created_date, now()) * 12 as month
FROM your_table;
```

Comment: I have edited the month calculation part as it was giving total months earlier. Can you check now?

Comment: getting error like this #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'p.year, u.createDate, now()) as year,TIMESTAMPDIFF(p.month, u.createDate, now())' at line 1

Comment: The first parameter should be YEAR or MONTH. You need to use like TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, u.createDate, now()).

Comment: database column year only?

Comment: It is a constant string. Check this :: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff